# Angular - how to call function in scripts.bundle.js from index.html

Tags: angular

I need to call a function from scripts.bundle.js from a --prod build.

We have this in the angular-cli json file:

```
  "scripts": [
      "./assets/scripts/analytics.js",
      "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
  ],
```

I need to use a function in scripts.bundle.js for analytics purposes when a user comes in with an unsupported browser like so in index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Detect browser and redirect IE11 or earlier users
(function() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE '); // IE10 or earlier
  var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/'); // IE11

   if ( msie > 0 || trident > 0 ) {
    analyticsTrack("/browser-error")
    window.location.href = "/browser-error.html";
   }
})();
</script>
```

This does not work because the scripts get injected at the bottom. At this point, analytics is not defined yet.

I tried putting the code in browser-error.html, by including it in scripts.bundle.js but once built with --prod, it doesn't work with cache-busting (because a hash gets injected into the name of the file - like scripts.sadf345dsfg.bundle.js)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    analyticsTrack("/browser-error")
    </script>
```

Are there other suggestions on how to call the function inside scripts.bundle.js aside from turning off cache-busting?

Comment: Did you try to put your script in a JS file and add it at the end the angular-cli json array ?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this and it worked:

Create a `test1.js` file that contains `var foo = 'bar';`

Create a `test2.js` file that contains `alert(foo);`

Put this in angular-cli.json :

```
"scripts": [
   "src/assets/scripts/test1.js",
   "src/assets/scripts/test2.js"
]
```

And when I ran this, I got an alert showing 'bar', so you could just put your script in a JS file and append it at the end of the angular-cli.json array.

Your script would benefit from minification and uglification thanks to Angular build.

Answer (score 0):

A co-worker helped me and his solution worked for me. I hope this helps other folks.

I added the script to the assets array on angular-cli.json (and still maintaining it on the scripts array).

```
  "scripts": [
      "./assets/scripts/analytics.js",
      "../node_modules/moment/min/moment.min.js",
...
  ],
```

and

```
  "assets": [
...
    "browser-error.html",
    "assets/scripts/analytics.js"
  ],
```

Then on the browser error page, instead of referencing scripts.bundle.js, I referenced that script.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/scripts/analytics.js"></script>
```

Works like a charm.

Comment: I did not get that you tried to call the script in another HTML page